# How to make Node Inspector (v0.12.8) work with Node v6.5.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

[Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) as of v0.12.8 seems broken when paired with Node v6.5.0 (at least on OS X El Capitan). When firing up `node-debug`, the browser is launched in order to debug the application as per usual, but the debugger fails quickly due to an exception caused by `InjectorClient.prototype._findNMInScope` not finding any 'NativeModule' property. See Node Inspector [issue #905](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/905) for reference.

How can Node Inspector be made to work with Node v6.5.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's native support for inspection in Node [from v6.5.0](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js), so Node Inspector might no longer be required. It can be invoked like so: `node --inspect --debug-brk my-app.js.` I've tried it, and it seems to basically work although I've yet to figure out how to actually use it.